# Laravel 5.5 . Как можно периодически менять данные на странице пользователя, после отложенных вычислений на сервере?

Tags: laravel

существует таск :

```
1) будет извлекаться пользователь и сохраняться в переменную $user = User::find(1);
2) дальше функция выводит experience;
3) Параллельно с работой функции асинхронный метод меняет опыт на случайное число каждые несколько секунд.      
В первой функции ещё раз выводится спустя промежуток времени опыт пользователя. Каким будет этот вывод ?
```

Как можно реализовать вывод на странице отложенных вычислений?
Правильно ли я понимаю, что должна быть следующая последовательность:
- на странице показывается опыт;
- параллельно - каждые 3 секунды, запускается обновление опыта;
- через минуту (к примеру) на странице обновляется значение опыт?

Comment: PHP - не асинхронный язык, тут нет действий *каждые 3 секунды*. Единственное решение - использовать асинхронные очереди, которые будут менять переменную в БД раз в 3 секунды. В Laravel это Queued Jobs. Пользователь же получает эти данные через ajax на странице.

Comment: Ну я собственно и кручусь вокруг очередей, jobs и scheduler.
Пока создал command и в scheduler установил отработку каждые 3 секунды. Но scheduler не срабатывает.

Когда вызываю command, срабатывает только она, без скедуляра. Как запустить command вместе со scheduler?

Comment: А зачем тут расписание вообще? У класса job есть параметр $delay, тут по расписанию делать вообще ничего не нужно

Comment: Разве роль delay - это не откладывание выполнения задачи на X время?
как можно с помощью Job и delay выполнять задачу каждые 3 секунды в течение минуты?

Comment: Поставить 20 задач?

Comment: спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Тут вся формулировка в целом смущает. Это далеко не таск, а хрен пойми что. Откуда выводится? Куда выводится? Куда эти данные передавать

Comment: @Alexxosipov
спасибо за помощь, реализовал через постановку 20 задач )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Готово.

Создаем Job, который рассчитан на 30 запросов в течение полутора минут. То-есть, каждые 3 секунды.

```
class UpdateUserExperienceJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;

    /**
    * Create a new job instance.
    *
    * @param User $user
    */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
    * Execute the job.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function handle()
    {
        for ($i = 3; $i <= 90; $i += 3) {
            sleep(3);
            $this->user->update(['experience' => rand()]);
        }
    }
}
```

Создаем метод в контроллере. В зависимости от параметра repeatRequest зависит запуск Job.

```
public function getExperience(): array
{
    $user = User::find(request()->get('user_id'));

    request()->get('repeatRequest') === 'true' ?: UpdateUserExperienceJob::dispatch($user);

    return ['experience' => $user->experience];
}
```

Фронт реализовывал через Vue.js . В компоненте, при загрузке, сперва получаем текущий опыт юзера, а потом каждые 5 секунд запускаем повторный запрос с положительным значеним свойства repeatedRequest. Благодаря вычисляемым свойствам (computed), значение будем менятся динамически.

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <p>experience is updated every 5 seconds</p>
        <p v-html="computedExperience"></p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                experience: 0,
                user_id: parseInt(document.URL.replace(/\D+/g,""))
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.firstExperience();
            setInterval(this.repeatedExperience.bind(this), 5000);
        },
        computed: {
            computedExperience() {
                return this.experience;
            },
        },
        methods: {
            firstExperience: function () {
                axios.get(document.URL + '/api', {
                    params: {
                        user_id: this.user_id,
                        repeatRequest: false
                    }
                }).then((response) => {
                    this.experience = response.data.experience;
                });
            },
            repeatedExperience: function () {
                axios.get(document.URL + '/api', {
                    params: {
                        user_id: this.user_id,
                        repeatRequest: true
                    }
                }).then((response) => {
                    this.experience = response.data.experience;
                });
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```